# Spark: custom Window function

Tags: apache-spark

I have a table of orders. For each order, there are various products which are present in different quantities. Example:

```
+---------------+-------------+--------+
|order_id       |   product_id|quantity|
+---------------+-------------+--------+
|A              |X            |       5|
|A              |Y            |       1|
|A              |Z            |       3|
```

A customer can then decide to return a product, and this will be marked as a negative quantity in the same order:

```
+---------------+-------------+--------+
|order_id       |   product_id|quantity|
+---------------+-------------+--------+
|A              |X            |       5|
|A              |Y            |       1|
|A              |Z            |       3|
|A              |X            |      -1|
|A              |Z            |      -1|
```

I need to create a new column, called position_number, which assigns a consecutive number to the records with positive quantity belonging to the same order (and this is easy, I just use a row_number function).
Then the difficult part: I have to assign the position_number to the records with negative quantities, by summing 1000 to the position_number of the corresponding product of the same order. 
The final result should be:

```
+---------------+---------------+-------------+--------+
|position_number|order_id       |   product_id|quantity|
+---------------+---------------+-------------+--------+
|              1|A              |X            |       5|
|              2|A              |Y            |       1|
|              3|A              |Z            |       3|
|           1001|A              |X            |      -1|
|           1003|A              |Z            |      -1|
```

How to do it? Any solution with Spark is appreciated (python, scala, SQL..)

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: I have a window function to calculate the position_number for the positive quantities:

val new_df = df
  .filter($"quantity" > 0)
  .withColumn("position_number", row_number.over(Window.partitionBy("order_id")))

Comment: you can do for two different case with `quality>=0` and `quality<0` and union them later.

Comment: yes but how to be able to have 1001 for the product X and 1003 for the product = Z? I need somehow to do position_number = 1000 + (position_number where quantity >0 and product_id = this)

Comment: so is `order_id A` and `product_id X` it always has at most two values right? Or is there a possibility of having another `A`  `X` and `10` maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Check if this is helpful -

```scala
  df.withColumn("is_negative", $"quantity" < 0)
      .withColumn("position_number", row_number()
      .over(Window.partitionBy($"order_id", $"is_negative").orderBy("product_id")))
      .withColumn("position_number",
        when($"is_negative", max(expr("if(is_negative, 0, position_number)"))
          .over(Window.partitionBy("order_id", "product_id")) + 1000)
          .otherwise($"position_number")
      )
      .show(false)

    /**
      * +--------+----------+--------+-----------+---------------+
      * |order_id|product_id|quantity|is_negative|position_number|
      * +--------+----------+--------+-----------+---------------+
      * |A       |Y         |1       |false      |2              |
      * |A       |Z         |3       |false      |3              |
      * |A       |Z         |-1      |true       |1003           |
      * |A       |X         |5       |false      |1              |
      * |A       |X         |-1      |true       |1001           |
      * +--------+----------+--------+-----------+---------------+
      */
```

Comment: That did exactly what I needed! Thanks a lot!